# Keep losing my index trying to pivot a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pivot-table, databricks

I have assigned four offers for each household and I have a dataframe with a row for each (i.e. the household appears in four rows, one for each offer).

```
HSHLD_NO, VAR_OFFER_NUM, var_offer_rank
10004, 12, 1
10004, 30, 2
10004, 23, 3
10004, 4, 4
10005, 14, 1
10005, 12, 2
10005, 15, 3
10005, 4, 4
```

[image]

I'm trying to create a new dataframe where I have one row for each household, and a column with each offer number. I'm trying

```
final_trans=df.pivot_table(index=['HSHLD_NO'], values='VAR_OFFER_NUM', columns=['var_offer_rank'])
```

but here's what I get:

1   2   3   4
12   30   23   4
14   12   15   4
[image]

I lose my household number on the left and cannot figure out how to keep it.

Comment: hey Allie, can you add some sample data that replicates your pic? since you shared a picture of your data I guess it's not private? do `print(df.head(15).to_dict()` and post the output into your question, highlight and click format as code.

Comment: Hi @Manakin I edited my question to include the sample data from the pics. The string of code you gave me didn't work (SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing) but I hope what I have is clear. Thank you

Comment: i do not get that output when I run your code, the `hshld_no` is in the index

Comment: my apologies I missed the last `)`  `print(df.head(15).to_dict())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is final_trans['HSHLD_NO'] = final_trans.index

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter='\s+')
print(df)
final_trans=df.pivot_table(index=['HSHLD_NO'], values='VAR_OFFER_NUM', columns=['var_offer_rank']) 
final_trans['HSHLD_NO'] = final_trans.index
print(final_trans)
```

Output:

```
   HSHLD_NO  VAR_OFFER_NUM  var_offer_rank
0     10004             12               1
1     10004             30               2
2     10004             23               3
3     10004              4               4
4     10005             14               1
5     10005             12               2
6     10005             15               3
7     10005              4               4
var_offer_rank   1   2   3  4  HSHLD_NO
HSHLD_NO
10004           12  30  23  4     10004
10005           14  12  15  4     10005
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I knew it had to be simple but couldn't find it anywhere online! I wasted so much time haha.